# Mysql ManyToMany relation log

Tags: mysql, logging, many-to-many, relation

I have a table, for example `orders`(id, name, product, ... ) and i have log table for it in which trigger writes: `orders_log(id, ts, order_id, name, product, ...)

Table `orders` has a ManyToMany relation for table `service`(id, name, price, ...) throught table `orders_services`(order_id, service_id)

User throught web form can add or delete services for order, and i must store log about this actions and show it to user when he edits order.

What is the best way to solve this problem? i have more than one manyToMany relations, and some one to oneToMany relations for the `orders` table.
I am using mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement a system based on triggers but I found it cumbersome and gave it up.

I had partial success with a system based on stored procedures that copied rows in shadow tables that contained the original fields +  a transaction id. I kept a separate table with the transaction id associated with information like date/user.  This system allowed us to assign a unique transaction id to a set of operations and later query these shadow tables based on these.

I am currently working in Java and my audit log is implemented by serializing my objects with XStream in a table that contains the class name, some locums that identify the id of the object, dates + the xml text. I think this is a good solution for an audit log as the information logged grows with your object model. It is also easy to create a report with the changes based on a diff between the subsequent xmls.